# How to make Windows 7 machine allocate a lot of hard disk cache?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, hard-drive-cache

I am recording some game play capture (recording playing of PS3 or Wii) using a PC with Windows 7 and [Hauppauge 1212 HD Recorder](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0018LX0DY), and I have 4GB of RAM... is there a way to increase the size of Windows 7's hard disk cache size so that writing to the hard drive can be super fast?  Since there is at least 1.5GB of RAM not being used, something like allocating 1GB just as hard disk cache, is it possible?

Comment: You mean "so that writing to the hard drive can **appear to be** super fast"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Google](http://www.google.com) to find [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/increase-the-filesystem-memory-cache-size-in-vista/). It should be relevant to Windows 7 as well.

```
fsutil behavior set memoryusage 2
```

Comment: do you even need to link Google?